# Why are email notifications not being delivered?

Tags: notification

I recently moved a number of sites to a new host and with that move have begun to have issues with email notification: new member, profile edit, new entry. The curious thing is that the notification issues are limited to domain-specific email accounts. For example, if I put a person from the client organization in the notification list as well as myself, and they have a company email associated with the domain and I include my email, which is not, I will get the notification but they don't.

Has anyone experienced this? If so, what could be the root cause? It is a challenge to take this issue to the hosting provider because they will see it as an Expression Engine problem, which of course they wouldn't support.

I am open to any and all suggestions for a solution to this.

Comment: If you have command line access to the web server can you use 'mail' from the command line and do some test cases?  If no access to command line can you write a simple php script that uses mail() and do some test cases?  Then present your test cases to the hosting company.  And if all your test cases work then you know it's an ee issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here has nothing to do with Expression Engine, but rather is an issue related to hosting multiple sites on a single account running Plesk. The solution requires some SSH into the server as noted here: http://www.serveridol.com/2011/03/16/disabling-email-service-for-a-domain-in-plesk/. Following those instructions resolved the problem.

Comment: A good way to debug sending email is first to try sending an email via the tools > communicate page. That way you can quickly test if the system is able to send emails at all (and easily retry, after you changed the Admin > email configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Postmaster paired with Mandrill is a nice solution for bulletproof email, so you don't have to deal with server issues like this. Not a direct solution to your problem, but, this approach has served me well recently.